# What is the Purpose of lockTheSwap modifier?

Tags: solidity

I have seen this modifier in many smart contract ls... please explain to me

```
modifier lockTheSwap {
inSwapAndLiquify = true;
_;
inSwapAndLiquify= false;,
}
```

Comment: It it a reentrancy guard? And if it is then how does it work? Also please explain thr variable inSwapAndLiquify

Comment: A reentrancy guard or mutex (mutually exclusive flag) can be built as a function or function modification. It is nothing but a piece of code responsible for causing the execution to fail whenever the act of reentrancy is found. Still, the idea is simple: a boolean lock is placed around the susceptible function call. The original state of “locked” is false (unlocked). Still, it is set to proper (locked) shortly before the vulnerable function execution begins and then reset to false (unlocked) when it ends.

I updated my answer with further explanations

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a simple re-entrancy guard in the form of a mutex.

It will prevent the protected functions from being re-entered in the same transaction.

There's likely a reference to `inSwapAndLiquify` modifier in the functions that have that modifier attached to them.

The `bool inSwapAndLiquify;` variable gets referenced in the modifier

```
modifier lockTheSwap {
 inSwapAndLiquify = true;
 _;
 inSwapAndLiquify = false;
};
```

And then further in an example function like this:

```
if (
            overMinTokenBalance &&
            !inSwapAndLiquify &&
            from != uniswapV2Pair &&
            swapAndLiquifyEnabled
        ) {
            contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
            //add liquidity
            swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
        }
```

Comment: Here's also an example Token contract that uses that modifier: https://github.com/milaabl/Baby-Floki-Coin

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mila's already great answer, in the context of auto-liquidity tokens this is used to avoid the contract being caught in a circular liquidity event (where swapAndLiquify triggers swapAndLiquify again),
let me explain :

when the transfer function of one of those contract is called, a portion of the transfer amount is collected by the contract as tax, and part of this tax is swapped to add liquidity to the token's LP.

However, during the swap, the contracts transfer function is called again (because swapping a token involves transferring it, of course), which could trigger the same mechanism again, potentially creating an infinite loop. To avoid that, before doing the actual swap we set that `inSwapAndLiquify` flag, and skip all the tax and swapAndLiquify logic when it is set.